# Can I conclude from object detection metrics on temporal behavior of a detection system?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, precision-recall, object-detection

Assuming I know typical object detection metrics like precision, recall etc. for a certain class, is there anyway to conclude on the probability that an object of that class which is present in several consecutive frames (e.g. when approaching an object in a video) is detected for at least 3, 5 or whatever number of consecutive frames?

For example, when passing 1000 traffic lights and each traffic is visible for lets say 100 frames and I know my object detector has 80 % chance of detecting a traffic light in a single image / frame, is there a way to conclude on how many traffic lights will be detected for example for at least 10 Frames?